# Using CASE Function with DATEDIFF and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Hi I'm sure this is a simple fix but I cannot figure it out. I'm trying to label records that are overdue the completion date (CompleteDate-CurrentDate) (these numbers will be negatives) to "Overdue" for a report. I would also like the records to not be altered for the numbers that are not negatives.  Here is a snippet of the code which is currently giving me NULL entries

```
Select    CASE DATEDIFF(targetcompletedate, NOW()) 
        When count(*) <=0 then 'Overdue'
    END 'Days Left',
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two variants of `CASE`:

1. ```
   CASE
     WHEN condition1 THEN result1
     WHEN condition2 THEN result2
     ...
     ELSE result_else
   END
   ```
2. ```
   CASE scalar_expression
     WHEN value1 THEN result1
     WHEN value2 THEN result2
     ...
     ELSE result_else
   END
   ```

In your case, it should be the first syntax, because you are not comparing to specific values but to a range. Instead, your query is actually using the second syntax. The `count(*)<=0` expression is evaluated to a boolean which is then implicitly converted to an integer, the type implied by the `DATEDIFF` result.

You just need to use the first syntax, something like this:

```
select case when targetcompletedate is null
            then 'Not set'
            when DATEDIFF(targetcompletedate, NOW()) <= 0
            then 'Overdue'                
            else DATEDIFF(targetcompletedate, NOW())
       end as 'Days Left'
```

Comment: is your `targetcompletedate` sometimes `null`? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you eliminate the `datediff()` entirely:

```
Select (CASE when targetcompletedate <= NOW() the 'Overdue' else 'Days Left' end)
```

If you want to show things as numbers, then you want the `datediff()`.  For clarity, I would explicitly convert to character strings:

```
select (case when targetcompletedate <= NOW() then 'Overdue'
              else cast(DATEDIFF(targetcompletedate, NOW()) as varchar(255))
        end)
```

Or, perhaps:

```
select (case when targetcompletedate <= NOW() then 'Overdue'
              else concat(DATEDIFF(targetcompletedate, NOW()), ' days left')
        end)
```

The philosophy being:  don't use a function if there is a simpler and clearer way to express what you want.

However, I wonder if you want to count the number in each group:

```
select sum(case when targetcompletedate <= NOW() then 1 else 0 end) as NumOverdue,
       sum(case when targetcompletedate <= NOW() then 0 else 1 end) as NumWithDaysLeft
```

Comment: This is great however I need the other records to show as numbers not as "Days Left" is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Just try this code:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN datediff(dd,targetcompletedate,now()) <= 0 THEN 'Overdue'
        WHEN datediff(dd,targetcompletedate,now()) > 0 THEN 'Days_left' 
    ELSE NULL END,
    datediff(dd,targetcompletedate,now()) AS 'days'
FROM tablename
```

The output is like:

Overdue -23

Days_left  13